# Last day of the previous month - In Specific format using JS

Tags: javascript, date

Want to display last day of the previous month using JS.

I need pure JS code than other Library.

Format Needed : Jan 31, 2017

Comment: tried anything from your side?

Comment: first search https://www.google.es/search?q=last+day+in+js+of+each+month&oq=last+day+in+js+of+each+month&aqs=chrome..69i57.6544j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Can you show us anything where you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: How will Jan 18, 2017 becomes last day of previous month? Could you explain the requirement and show your work?

Comment: @Nitheesh, Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) whenever I want work with dates which gives you lot's of options for format your date, but since you said with plain javascript, you can made a method like this to format your date :

```
function formatDate(date) {
   date.setDate(0);
   var monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
 ];

 var day = date.getDate();
 var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
 var year = date.getFullYear();

 return  monthNames[monthIndex] +  ' ' + day  + ' ' + year;
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
```

Basiclly `date.setDate(0);` will change the date to  last day of the previous month.

Comment: Thanks  @Emad Dehnavi - Helped me a lot

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this in 2021:
`date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' })` will achieve the same as above without the array of month names, and `date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' })` will give the format the OP asked for.